# Is it possible to use html5 speech API into android webview in kitkat?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

I have a very simple website that uses the html5 speech recognition API to convert audio to text. 
My goal is to make it work inside a webview in Android, but i get this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lang' of undefined", source: https://example.com/(216)

Any ideas?

**Here is my MainActivity:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");
    }
}
```

**Here is my javascript:**

```
var final_transcript = '';
var recognizing = false;

if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {

  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;

  recognition.onstart = function() {
    recognizing = true;
  }
  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.error);
  };

  recognition.onend = function() {
    recognizing = false;
  }


  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var interim_transcript = '';
    for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        document.getElementById("textresult").innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);
      } else {
        interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        document.getElementById("textresult").innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);
      }
    }
    final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);

    document.getElementById("textresult").innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);
    document.getElementById("textresult").innerHTML = linebreak(final_transcript);

  };
}

var two_line = /\n\n/g;
var one_line = /\n/g;
function linebreak(s) {
  return s.replace(two_line, '<p></p>').replace(one_line, '<br>');
}

function capitalize(s) {
  return s.replace(s.substr(0,1), function(m) { return m.toUpperCase(); });
}

function startDictation(event) {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    return;
  }
  final_transcript = '';
  recognition.lang = 'en-US';
  recognition.start();
  final_span.innerHTML = '';
  interim_span.innerHTML = '';
}

    </script>
```

Comment: your `recognition` variable is in a different scope

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Please check my answer and double check if `'webkitSpeechRecognition' in window` returns true

Answer (score 0):

Could you try declaring your `recognition` variable above this line?

```
if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)
```

Comment: That is assuming you only missed to paste a `}` on your `onEnd` function

Comment: Have you tried making your `recognition` a global var? Because i think the issue there is not really the capability of speech api in webview, but the variable is not accessible in your `startDictation` function

Comment: Have you checked if `'webkitSpeechRecognition' in window` returns true?

Comment: yes, it does. I also tried the js in chrome and it works, but inside webview doesn't